# Agregar filas al datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

estoy haciendo un sistema de punto de venta con lector de codigo de barras, los datos los cargo a un datagridview si agrego articulos con el mismo codigo de barras en la columna "cantidad" los suma automaticamente, pero al leer otro articulo con diferente codigo de barras en la primera lectura si lo agrega en una fila nueva, pero al agregar otr articulo igual, lo reescribe en la primera fila del datagridview, podrian ayudarme agrego parte del codigo para mayor explicacion

```
  If (e.KeyChar = (Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))) Then
                Dim conexion As SqlConnection
                conexion = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Gabriel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ventas;Integrated Security=True")
                conexion.Open()
                Dim cod As String = txt_No_Factura.Text
                Dim cadena As String = "select codigo_barra,idproducto,nombre,precio_venta from producto where codigo_barra ='" & cod & "'"
                Dim comando As SqlCommand
                comando = New SqlCommand(cadena, conexion)
                Dim registro As SqlDataReader
                registro = comando.ExecuteReader()
                registro.Read()


                cod_barra.Text = registro(0)
                txt_idproducto.Text = registro(1)
                txt_nombreProducto.Text = registro(2)
                txt_precioUnitario.Text = registro(3)

                datalistado.ColumnCount = 5
                With datalistado
                    .Columns(0).Name = "Cantidad"
                    .Columns(1).Name = "Codigo Barra"
                    .Columns(2).Name = "Codigo Producto"
                    .Columns(3).Name = "Nombre"
                    .Columns(4).Name = "Precio de Venta"
                End With
                conexion.Close()

                If datalistado.Rows.Count = Nothing Then
                    cantidad += 1
                    datalistado.Rows.Add()
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(0).Value = cantidad.ToString() - 1
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(2).Value = txt_idproducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(3).Value = txt_nombreProducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(4).Value = txt_precioUnitario.Text
                    'f = f + 1
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = ""
                End If

                If datalistado.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    For fila As Integer = 0 To datalistado.Rows.Count - 1

                        datalistado.CurrentCell = datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1)
                        If datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text Then 'cod.toString()
                            existe = True
                        End If
                        If datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value <> cod_barra.Text Then
                            existe = False
                        End If
                        Label15.Text = fila.ToString()
                    Next

                End If

                If existe = True Then
                    'f = f + 1
                    cantidad += 1
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(0).Value = (cantidad.ToString() - 1)
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(3).Value = txt_nombreProducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(4).Value = txt_precioUnitario.Text
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = "" ' agregue esto
                    'f = f + 1
                End If
                If existe = False Then
                    datalistado.Rows.Add(txt_cantiad.Text, cod_barra.Text, txt_idproducto.Text, txt_nombreProducto.Text, txt_precioUnitario.Text)
                    'f = f + 1
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = ""
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("El articulo no fue registrado cuando ingreso a almacen")
        End Try
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay varias cosas muy raras en este codigo. Fila donde esta definido? porque hay un if existe = true y despues un if existe = false? eso es if else... Hay algo de este codigo que suena raro.. cual es tu idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemillas en tu código,el principal es que, cuando buscas si una fila existe y la encuentras, no almacenas que fila es.

Crea una variable `Integer`  que se llame por ejemplo `FilaEncontrada`, si encuentras que la fila ya existe, almacena en esa variable que fila es, y usa esa nueva variable para actualizar el grid. En el siguiente código te muestro mas o menos como sería, y he modificado alguna cosa (cuando encuentras que una fila ya está en el grid, no hace falta seguir buscando por ejemplo):

```
Dim FilaEncontrada As Integer
If datalistado.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   existe = False
   For fila As Integer = 0 To datalistado.Rows.Count - 1
       datalistado.CurrentCell = datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1)
       If datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text Then 'cod.toString()
           existe = True
           FilaEncontrada=fila
           Exit For
       End If
   Next
   Label15.Text = FilaEncontrada.ToString()
End If

If existe = True Then
  cantidad += 1
  datalistado.Rows(FilaEncontrada).Cells(0).Value = (cantidad.ToString() - 1)
  datalistado.Rows(FilaEncontrada).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text
```

Comment: ok, gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Gracias Pikoh tus correcciones me ayudaron, funciona de maravilla, exitos !!